# "we are going to x, y, z" implicit order

Tags: list-order

When someone says "I'm going to x,y,z" is there an implicit order to this? Such as going to x first then y followed by z. If so what is this called?

I assuming that interpreting this sentence as the person going to z first then y and lastly x is also valid.

Comment: Unless there is another more plausible inherent order then the implied order is the order given: x,y,z.  But in something like, "I am going to mix, bake, and roll the dough" the actual order is less likely to be the order given.  But in that case I'd probably question the speaker: "You're gonna bake it before you roll it?!?" because there is an implied order in the statement which doesn't match how baking works.

Comment: When people make statements where the order given doesn't match the actual order they usually will add a caveat like:"But not in that order" or "The things I will do, alphabetically, are dress, eat, and shower."